# Help in understanding if the maximum likelhood estimation is working properly

Tags: matlab, self-study, parameter-estimation

I am learning estimation theory and need  help in understanding for educational purpose how the concept of ML works with the help of a step by step implementation. I am trying to find out the ML estimates of the coefficients of a moving average model. I am unable to understand what I need to do in order to get the log-likelihood curve, so that I can select the coefficients based on the curve. There are implementations in the internet but I wanted to make my own in order to get a clear picture. The way I have done is for the model

```
 y(i) =  0.6*x(i-1) ;
 z(i) = y(i) + w(i)
```

where the true coefficient is `h = [ 0.6]`, the input is `x` and `w` is zero mean additive white gaussian noise with variance 1. I have used 4 different values of the estimates out of which one value is the true. If the implementation is correct, then I should get estimated coefficient as 0.6 because I am using the true known coefficient in the estimation procedure. However, this is not so. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum likelihood estimator will give you precisely the true value for the parameter for a vanishingly small number of instances --- unless the noise is zero.

Your noise instance `w` is not zero-mean, which will probably give more of a bias away from the true value.

If I take your numbers are just change the last entry in `w` from `-0.65` to `0.1` then I get the "right" answer. Note that this changes the mean of `w` form `-0.16` to `-0.042` (i.e. closer to zero).

Your values:

[image]

The new values:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the details. I corrected my implementation and have got correct values till $(h*x-z)*(h*x-z)$. But, the values of the likelihood in the last column are very different from mine as a result I am getting the ML estimate of h as 0.4692.

Comment: Could you please let me know what is the formula that you used to calculate the likelihood values? I am getting different values and I checked using  L(iter) = exp(-sum((z(k)-new_output(iter,k)).^2)/(2*sigma2w)); still the values are different.

Comment: Lastly,  I had used the randn(N,1) command to generate noise samples. I think in Matlab, we can generate zero mean noise samples using this command. How can I generate noise samples which are zero mean like the ones that you suggest. Thank you very much once again

Comment: @SKM I didn't use the full equation. Just the sum of the squared term.

Comment: I dont' quite understand this part. Would it be possible to include that in your answer please how you calculated the likelihood values using the  the sum part ? Appreciate your help very much

Comment: I have updated the question with the new code. As can be seen the values of L are very different. I cannot understand how to correctly implement this crucial part. Please help.