# Notation confusion -- What is the correct operator for computation of the log-likelihood expression for complex valued data?

Tags: estimation, math, parameter-estimation

This question is an extension of another question of mine asked earlier here [Help in understanding if the maximum likelhood estimation is working properly](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35463/help-in-understanding-if-the-maximum-likelhood-estimation-is-working-properly)

In that question the inputs were real valued. Now, in this question the inputs are real valued and hence the confusion.

I am having difficulties in the notation when applying to the complex domain. 
What notations and operators should I use when all the data are complex valued? Please help

Comment: A likelihood is a (possibly conditional) probability density function/mass function -- it has to be real valued.

Comment: To me it's not yet clear: What are deterministic/known inputs, what is random, what do you want to estimate? What is $P_n$? what is $x^s$? Also, your log-likelihood in the bottom does not match the L-expression in the top?

Comment: Please let me know if more information is required. Thank you once again

Comment: I dont want to go through a full kalman-filter derivation here. But if it is just about adapting the notation: you define your signal model as you want.  When it's supposed to be convolution, keep it with transpose without conjugation. However, take care that your signal model is matching your numeric calculations. Whenever you have squared terms, e.g. $z_n(z_n-hx)$, you should conjugate the second term. This should yield the correct result.

Comment: Thank you, I have 3 more questions on adaptations could you kindly help : (1) Is the representaion of the model in eq(3) for complex correct? (2) For division like in the expression for $\mathbf{\hat{h}} =[.] −1 ∑[. ]$ under the update, would the {-1} in the power become  $−H$?(3) you mentioned the transpose without conjugation for evaluating the expression ${||x-y||}^2 = (x-y){(x-y)}^*$ -- so should I be doing `(x-y)*conj((x -y))`

Comment: 1) this depends on how you model your system. However, normally it would be with Hermitian instead of Transpose operation. (Especially, When considering the calculation as the inner product between h and x). 2) No, it will not become -H. It may become -H, if it was -T in the real domain, but it depends. In your special case, as P is a covariance matrix, -H and -1 are equivalent anyway. 3) Yes. Or just abs(x-y)**2

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the last point 3) There are two * operators, is that a typo ?

Comment: No, its the power of 2 in Python Notation. Or abs(x-y).^2 in Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your overall signal model we cannot really help. I suppose $y$ is your estimate? And hence, $L=L(y)$. Where is $h$ in your Likelihood equation? However, some general observations:

- As Batman pointed out: likelihood corresponds to probability, which is necessarily a real value. So, if your equations yield complex values, you did something wrong. (Note that, depending on numerical accuracies etc. it can happen, that there is a very small imaginary part ($\approx 10^{-16}$) in your numeric computations. This part can be ignored.)
- Commonly (but not always!) when in the real-domain you have a transpose in your equation, it changes to conjugate transpose (i.e. Hermitian operation) in the complex domain.
- Noise variances commonly remain real-valued. However, noise realizations will be complex-valued.
- You should understand the expression in your exponential as the squared distance between the measurement and the estimate. In real domain, the squared distance of $x,y$ is equal to $(x-y)^2$. However, in the complex domain, it becomes $\|x-y\|^2=(x-y)(x-y)^*$.